# Move row to different sheets based on value in 1 cell, but can't get it to take new row each time

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying out something, by looking at other code ecample and stuff like that.

But I have some problems.

In my data input sheet, i have a dropdown menu with possible Names. But from what I have made now in the code, it just delete that. It does not copy the data over in other sheet and then just blank it out in data sheet, so every time I would have to make the dropdown list again.

Also when it move it over, it first move it to row 2, then to row 4. So jump over row 3, but then after that it just go to row 4 again and overwrite what is in row 4.
I think I need some kind of variables here for each sheet, but Im not strong in VBA, so not sure how to do it.

Here is the code that I have.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim TargetCounters(3) As Integer
Dim TargetNames(3) As String
TargetNames(0) = "Co"
TargetNames(1) = "Od"
TargetNames(2) = "Th"
TargetNames(3) = "Ca"

Dim i As Integer
Dim shSource As Worksheet

Dim shTargets(3) As Worksheet

Set shSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data input")

For i = 0 To 3
Set shTargets(i) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(TargetNames(i))
If shTargets(i).Cells(2, 1).Value = "" Then
    TargetCounters(i) = 2
Else 
    TargetCounters(i) = shTargets(i).Cells(2, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 2
End If
Next i

i = 2
Dim MatchIndex As Integer

Do Until shSource.Cells(i, 1).Value = ""

        Select Case shSource.Cells(i, 1).Value
        Case "Co":
            MatchIndex = 0
        Case "Od":
            MatchIndex = 1
        Case "Th":
            MatchIndex = 2
        Case "Ca":
            MatchIndex = 3
        Case Else
            MatchIndex = -1
        End Select
        If (MatchIndex = -1) Then
            i = i + 1
        Else
            shSource.Rows(i).Copy
            shTargets(MatchIndex).Cells(TargetCounters(MatchIndex), 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            shSource.Rows(i).Delete
            TargetCounters(MatchIndex) = TargetCounters(MatchIndex) + 1
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Here is a link to the excel I made. Right now I only made it to move to 4 sheets, but when working I will be able to add the rest.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vvjt8z82xiuw9y1/Movedata.xlsm?dl=0

In short my problems is

It delete my dropdown list and it does not insert in a new free row everytime.

EDIT:

Have found out about the delete part now. Found there was function ClearContents instead of Delete.

Comment: Couldn't see drop down names. Is it Data Validation list or DropDown Form control?

Comment: Data validation.